# Excel Find First Instance of Value Larger Than Reference

Tags: vba, excel

Quick question. I am trying to create a program that finds the first instance of the value that is larger than the Maximum volume of a tank in I8. I want to compare the volumes in the Vol column in I13:I80 to the max volume in I8. I then want excel to output the corresponding Strap in column B13:B80 as a message box. So in this instance a message box would be outputted saying  "The height of the wall is 16 Inches" As B20 is the value of the strap that corresponds to the first volume greater than the max.

```
Public Sub dimensionInput()

Dim wallWidth As Double 'Get Wall Width Input
wallWidth = Application.InputBox("Input Desired Secondary Containment Wall Width in Inches", "Wall Width", 1)
If wallWidth = False Then
    Call zeroFill
    Exit Sub
Else
Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value = wallWidth
End If

Dim wallLen As Variant 'Get Wall Length Input
wallLen = Application.InputBox("Input Desired Secondary Containment Wall Width in Inches", "Wall Width", 1)
If wallLen = False Then
    Call zeroFill
    Exit Sub
Else
Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value = wallLen
End If

Dim arrayDia() As String
Dim diameter As Variant 'Get Diameter Input
diameter = Application.InputBox("Input Tank(s) Diameter Seperated by a Comma and Space e.g. N1, N2, N3, ...", "Diameter", 1)
arrayDia() = Split(diameter, ",")
For i = LBound(arrayDia) To UBound(arrayDia)
    Cells(6, i + 3).Value = arrayDia(i)
Next i

Dim arrayLen() As String
Dim length As Variant 'Get Lenth Input
length = Application.InputBox("Input Desired Length Seperated by a Comma and Space e.g. N1, N2, N3, ...", "Length", 1)
arrayLen() = Split(length, ",")
For i = LBound(arrayLen) To UBound(arrayLen)
    Cells(7, i + 3).Value = arrayLen(i)
Next i

'Dim arrayOrient() As String
'Dim orient As Variant 'Get Orient Input
'orient = Application.InputBox("Input Desired Orient", "Orient", H)
'arrayOrient() = Split(orient, ",")
'For i = LBound(arrayOrient) To UBound(arrayOrient)
'    Cells(9, i + 3).Value = arrayOrient(i)
'Next i

Dim arrayOffset() As String
Dim offset As Variant 'Get Offset Input
offset = Application.InputBox("Input Desired Offset Seperated by a Comma and Space e.g. N1, N2, N3, ...", "Offset", 0)
arrayOffset() = Split(offset, ",")
For i = LBound(arrayOffset) To UBound(arrayOffset)
    Cells(10, i + 3).Value = arrayOffset(i)
Next i

End Sub

Public Sub zeroFill()

Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:H7").Value = "0"
'Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C9:H9").Value = "H"
Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10:H10").Value = "0"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I think what @Tom is trying to say, is what have you done so far? Folks at SO will help you fix code that doesn't work, but most won't actually write it for you - at least not without a signed contract.

Comment: I have added the code that I used for the project. I didn't want anyone to get the idea I want it done for me. If anything I'd really like to understand how to do it. I am just not a great programmer, apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: I would love that! I feel I am going to be using excel more and more so a clearer understanding would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having suggested the formula:

```
="The height of the wall is"&INDEX(B13:B80,MATCH(I8,I13:I80,1)+1)&""""
```

OP indicated some explanation of it would be appreciated.

[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Looks for the relevant value (`I8`) in the range `I13:I80`. Since results are required for a single cell (no formula dragging involved) anchors (`$` for fixing references) are not required.

The third parameter (here `1`) per M$:

> finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value.

So given `872.9` (in I8) the 'matched' value of `794.4` is the seventh item in the range (counting down). That is not enough (we are looking for *First Instance of Value Larger Than Reference*) so we step down one row (since the data is sorted ascending) with `+1`. So we now have the index (8) of the relevant row in the range. This is applied to:

[INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) (array form)

which considers a range (here `B13:B801`) and picks from it the value of the `n`th entry (row_number counting from the top of the range). Here as n=8 this is `16`.

For the message box a little more than plain `16` is required and the explanatory text can be added with [concatenation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d).

OP asked for `Inches` rather than `"` but for a message box `"` seemed adequate to me and the capitalisation inappropriate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have values in column **I** from **I3** through **I19**.  Place the reference value in cell **K3**.  In **J3** enter:

```
=IF(I3>$K$3,I3,"")
```

In **J4** enter:

```
=IF(AND(I4>$K$3,COUNT($J$3:$J3)=0),I4,"")
```

and copy down.  Finally in **L3** enter:

```
=MAX(J:J)
```

[image]

*(This method avoids array formulas)*